# Lagging while iterating Java RecordSet

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, recordset

I have CallableStatement which I use to retrieve about 500 records from DB using store procedure.

I get back results on average at 300ms, BUT processing all those records take about 1-2 seconds.

```
CallableStatement a = connection.prepareCall("SP_HERE",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        a.setFetchSize(4000);
```

Than: (I get few views in response)

```
        boolean hadResults = a.execute();
        while (hadResults) {

            ResultSet rs = a.getResultSet();

            List<Map<String,DBInput>> tmpDB = processResultSet(rs);
            ...
            hadResults = a.getMoreResults();    

        }
```

The lagging part is here:

```
private List<Map<String,DBInput>> processResultSet (ResultSet rs){

    List<Map<String,DBInput>> dbIn = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        while (rs.next()){

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            Map<String,DBInput> map = new HashMap<>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {

                String columnName = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);

                DBInput tmp = new DBInput();

                int columnType = rsmd.getColumnType(i);

                 Object value = null;
                 int type = OEMIO.NULL;
                 long timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
                 switch (columnType){

                 case VARCHAR:

                     value = rs.getString(i);
                     type = OEMIO.STRING;
                     break;

                 case CHAR:

                     value = rs.getString(i);
                     type = OEMIO.STRING;
                     break;

                 case INTEGER:

                     value = rs.getInt(i);
                     type = OEMIO.INTEGER;
                     break;

                 case DECIMAL:

                     value = rs.getBigDecimal(i);

                     if (value != null) value = ((BigDecimal)value).doubleValue();
                     type = OEMIO.DOUBLE;
                     break;

                 case TIMESTAMP:

                    if (rs.getTimestamp(i) == null) break;

                     value = rs.getTimestamp(i).toString();

                     if(rs.getTimestamp(i).toString().contains(" ")){

                         value = rs.getTimestamp(i).toString().replace(" ", "T") + "Z";
                     }
                     type = OEMIO.DATE;
                     break;

                 case DATE:

                     if (rs.getDate(i) == null) break;

                     value = rs.getDate(i).toString();

                     if(rs.getDate(i).toString().contains(" ")){

                         value = rs.getDate(i).toString().replace(" ", "T") + "Z";
                     }

                     type = OEMIO.DATE;
                     break; 

                case BIT:

                     value = rs.getBoolean(i);
                     type = OEMIO.BOOLEAN;
                     break; 

                default:

                    value = "NO TYPE IDENTIFIED";
                    type=-1;
                 }
                long timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long diff = timeAfter-timeBefore;
                if (diff > 10) {

                    logger.debug("Column: " + diff + "ms" + "  " + columnType + "  index id: " + i);
                    OrdersManagerThread.type.add(columnType+"");
                }

                 tmp.setDbInput(columnName);
                 tmp.setType(type);
                 tmp.setValue(value);
                 map.put(columnName, tmp);

            }

            dbIn.add(map);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        logger.error("Error parsing ResultSet: " + e.getMessage());

    }finally{

        rs.close();
    }

    return dbIn;
}
```

From some reason I don't get WHY In sometimes switch case is lagging while getting results from RecordSet? 
here are the test prints:

Column: 170ms  12  index id: 34

Column: 165ms  12  index id: 50

Column: 142ms  12  index id: 55

Column: 171ms  12  index id: 4

Column: 180ms  12  index id: 76

Column: 151ms  12  index id: 68

Column: 80ms  12  index id: 62

Column: 90ms  3  index id: 16

Column: 79ms  12  index id: 9

Column: 89ms  12  index id: 4

Column: 85ms  3  index id: 15

Column: 85ms  1  index id: 10

Column: 101ms  12  index id: 4

What might cause those lags?

Thanks

UPDATE:

adding

```
    **Thread.sleep (10000);**
    boolean hadResults = a.execute();
    while (hadResults) {

        ResultSet rs = a.getResultSet();

        List<Map<String,DBInput>> tmpDB = processResultSet(rs);
        ...
        hadResults = a.getMoreResults();    

    }
```

"Fix" the problem. what might cause that to happen ? or does it gives any direction for a fix ?

Answer (score 0):

your fetch size looks small.  That might cause additional round-trips to the server.  Try increasing it.  I'd start off with something big enough to hold the entire result set, if you can, then back off to find a happy balance between memory and I/O

Comment: Look at my update, I've increased fetch size but it did not change the result. only waiting before processing ResultSet for some reason  changed the outcome.